# What are the historical reasons that "streams" are called FILE in C

Tags: c, unix, stream, history, libc

The [GNU libc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Streams.html#Streams) mentions that there are historical reasons that the data structure representing "streams" is called FILE.

After getting curious i've googled around and tried to look into it but I can't seem to find this fabulous tale.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't have a citation for this, it's likely that the historical reason *for the creation of the term "stream"* is standardization of the C language. `FILE` is the type that was always used with `FILE *` handles for stdio in C, but in order to express the specification for the stdio interfaces, it's necessary to be able to distinguish between a *file* (the actual storage object) and the handle for an open file, and "stream" seems to have been the word that was chosen.